# Error: "Illegal query syntax. Segment before '/' is not an entity or complex type."

Tags: nested, odata, expand

I am trying to use filter query in nested `$expanded` entity.

For example, I am using the below query.

```
webservice/Results?$expand=FoodDescriptions&$filter=substringof('Vod', FoodDescriptions/Description)&$format=json
```

While executing this, I am getting the below error

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Illegal query syntax. Segment before '/' is not an entity or complex type."
        }
    }
}
```

I got this query from the below public service example.

```
https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$expand=Customer&$filter=substringof('Henriette', Customer/ContactName)&$format=json
```

in this case, I am getting proper response and anyone can test it.

Can someone tell me what could be the reason for this particular error in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies most likely under ODataConfig - You dont have `FoodDescriptions` set as Entity.

If you go over here [https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata], you can find this line `<EntitySet Name="Customers" EntityType="NorthwindModel.Customer"/>`

In your case, you probably just forgot to register *FoodDescriptions* as entity.

Comment: yes, this was the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you! Could you mark my answer as Answer? Thank you in advance.